# How can I get a list of child processes for a given service in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, process, service

I have a service which creates a number of child processes. Using c# I need to determine the number of these child processes which are currently running.

For example I have a service running called "TheService". This spawns 5 child processes, all called "process.exe". Is it possible to determine the number of child processes running under the service? Essentially I need to know the number of instances of "process.exe" given only the name of the service/service process name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use WMI, the [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx) class includes the parent process id. So a WQL query (see System.Management namespace for WMI under .NET) like:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Process Where ParentProcessId = n
```

replacing *n* with the service's process id.

EDIT Sample code (based on code by [Arsen Zahray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847200/arsen-zahray)):

```
static List<Process> GetChildProcesses(int parentId) {
  var query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessId = "
          + parentId;
  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
  ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

  var result = processList.Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(p =>
    Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(p.GetPropertyValue("ProcessId")));
  ).ToList();

  return result;
}
```

Comment: does this list only the 32 bit processes??

Comment: @It'satrap: no (just checked where the parent is 32bit and the child is 64).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I myself also verified.

Comment: Be very VERY careful with this (I found out the hard way). Root level processes in Windows tend to be orphaned (wininit.exe, cssrss.exe) but still have a parent ID. The parent no longer exists, so its ID is used for new processes. When querying for a process' children, those orphaned root level processes are returned as well. Solution, check the start time of the children and make sure they were started AFTER the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by "the name of the service" - would that be process.exe?

If so, the static method [Process.GetProcessesByName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) should do the trick:

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("process");
Console.WriteLine(procs.Length);
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. Having thought about it a bit more I realise that I just need to get the number of child processes for a given process name. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ok. Richard's answers should solve it then. I withdraw my answer, but unless someone objects, I will leave it here, as it might just help others in the future... :)