# Listing all children of a process

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to list all the children of a given process (given it's process ID).
After some research I have come to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    listChildProcesses(0);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void listChildProcesses(int parentProcessId)
{
    String myQuery = string.Format("select * from win32_process where ParentProcessId={0}", parentProcessId);
    ObjectQuery objQuery = new ObjectQuery(myQuery);
    ManagementObjectSearcher objSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection processList = objSearcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject item in processList)
    {
        try
        {
            int processId = Convert.ToInt32(item["ProcessId"].ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("processId:{0} name:{1} {2}",
                item["ProcessId"],
                item["Name"],
                item["ParentProcessId"]
            );

            // recursive call
            if (processId != parentProcessId)
                listChildProcesses(processId);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping this would allow me to display all processes (since the method starts at PID=0 and then is recursively called on each PID found from there).

But here is the output I get on my Windows 8 (x86):

```
processId:0 name:System Idle Process 0
processId:4 name:System 0 
processId:300 name:smss.exe 4
```

It stops there. I would expect it to keep going on with each child of System and then each child of those children.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of child processes for a given sevice in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073615/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-child-processes-for-a-given-sevice-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I actually saw that one earlier while trying to understand this. But it makes no mention of the issue I'm having as to why the recursive call doesn't list them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing what you're thinking...

that way you're just listing children. And you're accessing the idle one by '0'.

Try something like this to get all processes...

```
ManagementClass mngcls = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");
foreach (ManagementObject instance in mngcls.GetInstances())
{
    Console.Write("ID: " + instance["ProcessId"]);
}
```

...then what you're doing.

Comment: If you do have a minute though, I would like to understand why my code doesn't work?
I actually wanted to do this recursively: start from process 0, get all children of 0, move on to first child, get all children...

Comment: simply put, your reasoning was wrong, as `process 0` is not the `root`, just another process - there isn't such a thing as a root of a tree (to my knowledge), so you have to use different queries to get one, then the other - if you combine it's just the same