# C# Find and handle child processes of a process

Tags: c#

i need help finding the child processes (they are 2) of a process and handle them in order to set each of them foreground when needed.
The main process is Java Platform SE binary whose indicative name is javaw.
Using this code:

```
Process[] arrProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("javaw");
```

I can get the main process, so with:

```
 IntPtr ipHwnd = arrProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;
 SetForegroundWindow(ipHwnd);
```

I can set it foreground.
My problem is that the handled process is the "last used" process...
Explaning better: on application bar of Windows I have 2 application(A, B) using java, if i click on A, when i use the code above, the application A gets foreground, insted, if i click on application B, with that code the B gets foreground.
What i want to do is decide which of two set foreground.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643846/listing-all-children-of-a-process